# Displaying fetched profile picture and user details in another activity in android studio

Tags: android-studio

Settings activity where data shoudl be displayed
(https://i.stack.imgur.com/JcKpB.png)
Profile acitivity where from where data should be fetched
(https://i.stack.imgur.com/dyxpf.png)

The image is being imported from gallery and the name and phone number is entered in profile acitivity.when i click back button the same name, email and image in profile acitivity should be displayed in my settings activity.
image is not one specific image any image imported from gallery should be displayed in settings activity.
I don't know how to do it